# how are you suppose to use the param tag

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, roslaunch, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im using rtabmap and i think im using the params wrong. where do i need to place them do they need to go inside the node tag like:

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry">
        <param name="Odom/ResetCountdown"              value="1" />
</node>
```

or does it need to be outside the node tag like:

```
<param name="Odom/ResetCountdown"              value="1" />

<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry">
</node>
```

or do both methods work and if they do whats the different between the 2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366293/how-are-you-suppose-to-use-the-param-tag/) by [MisticFury](https://answers.ros.org/users/58812/misticfury/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This one works:

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry" output="screen">
        <param name="Odom/ResetCountdown"              value="1" />
</node>
```

Log:

```
...
[ INFO] [1606258509.200716411]: Setting odometry parameter "Odom/ResetCountdown"="1"
...
```

For rgbd_odometry, those parameters are private. To use the other approach, you should do (prefix with name of the node):

```
<param name="rgbd_odometry/Odom/ResetCountdown"              value="1" />
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry" output="screen"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MisticFury](https://answers.ros.org/users/58812/misticfury/) on 2020-11-24**:
ok i don't understand why but that still doesn't set the parameter and i decided to just rtabmap and do rosparam list and for some reason i don't see any of the odom parameters the 2 im trying to change are Odom/ResetCountdown and Odom/Strategy

**Comment by [MisticFury](https://answers.ros.org/users/58812/misticfury/) on 2020-11-24**:
nvm figured it out

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2020-11-25**:
rosrun rtabmap_ros rgbd_odometry --params